# Get instance of File from /assets/ in android

Tags: java, android, file

I would like to create a new instance of `File` from an asset in my android project.

I found a lot of solutions to read the file into bytes or a string, but not how to create a `java.io.File` instance from it.

Comment: use `FileOutputStream`

Comment: please elaborate or link, thanks

Comment: use google, it has a lot of links

Comment: i suggest `AssetManager` class

Comment: It does not have a method that returns an instance of java.io.File, as far as I know.

Comment: Why you need File instance, use assetManager.open("file"), it return an InputStream

Comment: I use MetaioSDK 6 and I want to load my trackingData using `metaioSDK.setTrackingConfiguration(trackingConfig);` which takes a `java.io.File` parameter

Comment: just copy your asset file using 1) `AssetManager#open(String fileName)` which gives you an `InputStream` and 2) `FileOutputStream` to save that `InputStream` to a `File`